# combining rows in same table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, max

**sample_data**

```
id_type,seq_no,acct_name,_acct#,address
12345,67,jiimm,,167 s.40th st
12345,67,jiimm joe the 3rd,,167 s.40th st
12345,67,jiimm
12345,67,,0981_1,po box 1234
12345,80,Lee,,1234 street ave
12345,80,Lee
12345,80,,588_1,109 road st
```

**CODE**

```
SELECT `ID`_type,
       seq_no,
       MAX(`acct_name`) AS acct_name,
       MAX(`acct_#`) AS acct_#,
       address
FROM `test_table`
GROUP BY `ID`_type,
         seq_no;
```

---

I want to merge rows based on by id_type and seq_no.  I am using max to merge the rows but I am overwriting any exisiting addresses and acct_names due to the MAX acct#.

**my results**

```
id_type,seq_no.,acct_name,_acct#,address
12345,67,jiimm joe the 3rd,0981_1,167 s.40th st
12345,80,Lee,588_1,109 road st
```

- Losing po box 1234 for 67-
- Losing 1234 street ave for 80, losing jiimm-

**desired results**

```
12345,80,Lee,588_1,109 road st
12345,80,Lee,588_1,1234 street ave    
12345,67,jiimm,0981_1,167 s.40th st
12345,67,jiimm,0981_1,po box 1234
12345,67,jiimm joe the 3rd,0981_1,167 s.40th st
```

Comment: In the 4th line of your input data sample, the acct_name is not present. In your desired results, you call for delivering the 4th input line with "jiimm" in the acct_name, however, there appear to be two account names to choose from "jiimm" and "jiimm joe the 3rd", both of which are sourced from lines with the same id_type and seq_no. What rule / logic should be used in determining how to pick one acct_name when there are multiple to choose from?

Comment: Supporting Mike Jones: If relying on `MAX`, you'd get `jiimm joe the 3rd`rather than `jiim` as in your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you what you're looking for, but read my comment / question underneath your question above. There is an ambiguous "pick one row from many" situation that needs clarification. In that ambiguous situation, you imply that rules call for delivering the minimum non-blank account name, which this code does, but you can see how it requires treating the account name one way, and treating the acct (#) and address a different way. I think you're headed for an application that delivers results based on hard to remember rules. Funky rules like that end up getting reported as defects, even if you publish said processing rules. Hence, you may want to enhance the process upstream that captures this data to deliver more disciplined data.

[SQLFIDDLE link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d511d0/12/0)  - In short the inner query populates missing values, then the outer result set delivers the distinct rows.  I tested this with blank values not null. I did make a quick effort to add the code to handle nulls, but I didn't test it using nulls, so I suggest testing it as such if that is what production will use.

```
select distinct * from (

  select     d.id_type, d.seq_no
            ,coalesce( nullif( acct_name, ''), min_acct_name ) as merged_acct_name
            ,coalesce( nullif( acct, ''),      max_acct      ) as merged_acct
            ,coalesce( nullif( address, ''),   max_address )   as merged_address
  from       test_table  d
  left join  ( select   id_type, seq_no
                       ,max( acct )      as max_acct
                       ,max( address )   as max_address
               from     test_table 
               group by id_type, seq_no
             ) as max_
        on   max_.id_type = d.id_type and max_.seq_no = d.seq_no
        and  (   coalesce( d.acct,'' )      = '' 
              or coalesce( d.address,'' )   = '' )
  left join  ( select   id_type, seq_no
                       ,min( acct_name ) as min_acct_name
               from     test_table 
               where    coalesce( acct_name, '' ) <> ''
               group by id_type, seq_no
             ) as min_
        on   min_.id_type = d.id_type and min_.seq_no = d.seq_no
        and  coalesce( d.acct_name,'' ) = ''
  ) as t

order by id_type, seq_no desc, merged_acct_name, merged_acct, merged_address
```

Comment: Quick question.  What if I wanted to add more fields in the select statement (the second one after the select distinct)?  This works well with my data, but I want my results to fit a different column header?  @Mike Jones

Comment: Void that last comment.  I figured it out. I was ordering the columns that I have along with the ones you provided me, hence creating extra columns of unprocessed data.  Instead I plugged in the fields you showed me how to modify in the sequential order they belong.  I choose your answer.

Comment: Mike Jones' [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d511d0/8) shows six rows returned, whilst the desired result has five. How did you adjust for that?

Comment: I think I missed refreshing the SQL fiddle link after I made one last code change. I've refreshed the link which now points to the code above and delivers 5 rows. I'm new to using SQL fiddle and just learned something about how it works regarding code iterations and changing links.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! (What I like so much about SQL Fiddle, is its ease of use - for those who want to see the code in action. Didn't really think of comparing source up here and over there. Sorry.)

Comment: Is there a way to make this an update query at all @MikeJones

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select    distinct t1.id_type, t1.seq_no
          ,coalesce( t1.acct_name, t2.acct_name ) as merged_acct_name
          ,coalesce( t1.acct,      t2.acct      ) as merged_acct
          ,coalesce( t1.address,   t2.address )   as merged_address
from       test_table  t1
left join  test_table  t2
  on t1.id_type = t2.id_type
  and t1.seq_no = t2.seq_no
where concat(coalesce( t1.acct_name, t2.acct_name ) 
          ,coalesce( t1.acct,      t2.acct      )
          ,coalesce( t1.address,   t2.address )  ) is not null
order by t1.id_type, t1.seq_no;
```

Or:

```
select    distinct t1.id_type, t1.seq_no
          ,coalesce( t1.acct_name, t2.acct_name ) as merged_acct_name
          ,coalesce( t1.acct,      t3.acct      ) as merged_acct
          ,coalesce( t1.address,   t4.address )   as merged_address
from       test_table  t1
left join  test_table  t2
  on t1.id_type = t2.id_type
  and t1.seq_no = t2.seq_no
left join  test_table  t3
  on t1.id_type = t3.id_type
  and t1.seq_no = t3.seq_no
left join  test_table  t4
  on t1.id_type = t4.id_type
  and t1.seq_no = t4.seq_no
where concat(coalesce( t1.acct_name, t2.acct_name ) 
          ,coalesce( t1.acct,      t3.acct      )
          ,coalesce( t1.address,   t4.address )  ) is not null
order by t1.id_type, t1.seq_no;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/868df/6)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  D1.id_type
  , D1.seq_no
  , IFNULL(D1.acct_name, (SELECT MIN(acct_name) FROM data D WHERE D.id_type = D1.id_type AND D.seq_no = D1.seq_no)) t
  , IFNULL(D1.acct_no, (SELECT MAX(acct_no) FROM data D WHERE D.id_type = D1.id_type AND D.seq_no = D1.seq_no)) s
  , D1.address
FROM data D1
WHERE D1.address IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id_type, seq_no DESC, acct_name
;
```

returns

```
| ID_TYPE | SEQ_NO |                 T |      S |         ADDRESS |
|---------|--------|-------------------|--------|-----------------|
|   12345 |     80 |               Lee |  588_1 |     109 road st |
|   12345 |     80 |               Lee |  588_1 | 1234 street ave |
|   12345 |     67 |             jiimm | 0981_1 |     po box 1234 |
|   12345 |     67 |             jiimm | 0981_1 |   167 s.40th st |
|   12345 |     67 | jiimm joe the 3rd | 0981_1 |   167 s.40th st |
```

Which is consistent with your expected output except for the order of the third and fourth row. However, for larger amounts of data `MAX` and `MIN` will become more and more likely to be of limited help.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/042cb/20/0)